# Can't get active worksheet or selected range when other Excel instance has focus

Tags: excel, office-js

I am maintaining an Office Add-In that receives data from a server and writes it to the current selection in the active worksheet.

When I open a seconds workbook, the Add-In in the first workbook is not able to get the active worksheet anymore.

When I focus the first workbook it's working again.

I am trying to get the active worksheet like this:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
  var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
  // insert code following ...
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error at WorksheetCollection.getActiveWorksheet
InvalidSelection: The current selection is invalid for this operation.
 at Anonymous function 
  (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.debug.js:12439:6)
 at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch 
  (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.debug.js:9240:8)
 at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback 
  (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.debug.js:9250:8)
 at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish 
  (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.debug.js:9226:9)
 at lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush 
  (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.debug.js:9060:8)
```

Getting the selected range of the workbook doesn't work either:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
  var range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange().getCell(0, 0);
  // ...
}
```

Similar Error:

```
Error at Workbook.getSelectedRange
InvalidSelection: The current selection is invalid for this operation.
 at Anonymous function 
  (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.debug.js:12439:6)
 at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch 
  (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.debug.js:9240:8)
 at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback 
  (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32.16.01.debug.js:9250:8)
 at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish 
  (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.debug.js:9226:9)
 at lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush 
  (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.debug.js:9060:8)
```

This problem has just appeared recently.

**Update**: It turned out that the previous statement was wrong, behavior was always like this (tested with a new MSI installation without any updates installed).

I was not able to reproduce it by starting two instances from Visual Studio.

In a Word Add-In `ctx.document.getSelection()` works as expected.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that this has been working this way. When you say that it used to work before, could you provide more information on which build/version of Excel it used to work? We will do more investigation to see if this is a behavior change.

If the workbook is not active, then the getActiveWorksheet() is expected to fail as it's not in active state.

**UPDATE:**
Now we support Workbook.getActiveWorksheet() to return the active worksheet on the workbook no matter the workbook is active or not. If you want to keep track of the selected range, you may use [Workbook.onSelectionChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook?view=excel-js-preview#onselectionchanged).

Comment: Ok, lets suppose that this has been working this way. How do I get the current selection of the workbook in which the Add-In is running?

Comment: We will do more internal discussion on the expected behavior, and will see if a change should be made here for the API. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Wenbo Shi, any news about this?

Comment: Now we support Workbook.getActiveWorksheet() to return the active worksheet on the workbook no matter the workbook is in active or not. If you want to keep track of the selected range, you may use [WorkSheetCollection.onSelectionChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetcollection?view=excel-js-preview#onselectionchanged).

Comment: fyi: I was able to solve the issue with you last hint about `onSelectionChanged` event. Instead of the event on the `Worksheet` I used the one on the `Workbook` since it is available in a lower API level. Unfortunately it is not available in Excel API 1.1

Answer (score 1):

If the second workbook is selected the initial workbook - and therefore your desired worksheet - will no longer be tagged as the activeworksheet.

You should be careful using activeworksheet when switching focus in excel workbooks.

My advice would be to catch and store the name of the activeworksheet in a variable, or to just plain hard code it, then use this variable in all future references

Comment: But why? In my opinion this is definitely a bug.
The active worksheet should always be the selected worksheet of the workbook where the Add-In is running. Why should another workbook affect this. It was working last year and it is working when I start two instances from Visual Studio.
But thanks for the hint how to workaround it.

Comment: The active worksheet is the active worksheet - I have created many macros where multiple excel documents are considered, so it is essential that the macro can reference any of the excel instances - and for this reason, activeworksheet must move with which workbook is in focus, otherwise it wouldn't be the active worksheet :)

Comment: Why does it work with multiple instances started from Visual Studio then?

Comment: An Add-In is not a macro. The Add-In is only inserted into one workbook so it should return the active worksheet of THAT workbook. At the risk of repeating myself: It WAS working that way until recently.

Comment: I just found out that the exact same error appears when I use `ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange()` directly. In Word `ctx.document.getSelection()` works as expected. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to register a `WorksheetActivatedEvent`, track the worksheet name in the event, and then you could use get the selected worksheet from name, when your workbook lost the focus.

it would be great if you could share your scenario, which help us understand more about the issue.